# IronPython Memory Leak When Calling Function With More Than 13 Parameters

Tags: function, memory-leaks, ironpython

I'm using IronPython 2.6.2 for .NET 4.0 as a scripting platform within a C#/WPF application. Scripts can include their own function definitions, class definitions, etc. I'm not restricting what can be written.

A memory leak appeared in the scripting piece recently after a script change. After commenting out more and more code, we determined that defining and calling a function with more than 13 parameters causes a memory leak. So if you call a function with 14 parameters IronPython will leak.

Here is some sample code on a timer running every 100ms:

```
  _Timer.Enabled = false;
  try
  {
    var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
    engine.Execute("def SomeFunc(paramI, paramII, paramIII, paramIV, paramV, paramVI, paramVII, paramVIII, paramIX, paramX, paramXI, paramXII, paramXIII, paramXIV):\r\n\tpass\r\nSomeFunc(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14)");
    //engine.Execute("def SomeFunc(paramI, paramII, paramIII, paramIV, paramV, paramVI, paramVII, paramVIII, paramIX, paramX, paramXI, paramXII, paramXIII):\r\n\tpass\r\nSomeFunc(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13)");

    // With and without the following line makes no difference
    engine.Runtime.Shutdown();

    this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate()
    {
      this.Title = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    });

  }
  catch (Exception)
  {


  }
  _Timer.Enabled = true;
```

Note that I have a 14-parameter version of the script and below it is a commented-out 13-parameter version. The Python script is basically this:

```
    def SomeFunc(paramI, paramII, paramIII, paramIV, paramV, paramVI, paramVII, paramVIII, paramIX, paramX, paramXI, paramXII, paramXIII, paramXIV):
        pass
    SomeFunc(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14)
```

I've tried with and without engine.Runtime.Shutdown() but it makes no difference. The 14-parameter version's memory will climb rapidly and the 13-parameter version's memory will climb slightly and then stabilize.

Any thoughts?

Thanks
- Shaun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a magic number of parameters in IronPython - less than that is a different (faster) code path than more. It sounds like there are still some bugs in the fallback code. Can you please [open an issue](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic) with a self-contained test case?

Looking at the latest code I would think the boundary would be at 15. Can you try again on 2.7 Beta 2 and see if the results are the same?

Comment: Thanks, Jeff. I tried 2.7 Beta 2 and had the same results. Running the app with the 14-parameter version of the "bare-metal" script leaked memory rapidly but the 13-parameter version consumed some memory and then stabilized.

Comment: For any that are interested, I have submitted a bug to the IronPython project on CodePlex complete with a code sample that demonstrates the issue. http://ironpython.codeplex.com/workitem/30131